# React router dom routing to ItemDetail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am doing a personal React.js project. I am trying to use react-router-dom, but I haven't been able to make it work. I did the BrowserRouter in the App.js. Till there the app works fine, but I cannot make the routing redirect dynamically to a map item. I tried to follow the documentation and some tutorials unsuccesfully. The data comes from the [Star Wars API](https://www.swapi.tech/) This is the code:
App.js:

```
import './App.css';    
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";    
import Home from './components/Home';
import MovieDetail from './components/MovieDetail'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <>
      <Navbar />
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>    
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path to='/:movieId' element={<MovieDetail />} />
        </Routes> 
        </>  
    </Router>  
  );
}

export default App;
```

ItemDetail:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";    
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const MovieDetail = () => {
    const { movieId } = useParams();

    const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("https://www.swapi.tech/api/films/");
        const json = await res.json();
        setResult(json.result);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    let movieMatch = (result.find(value) => value.properties.title == movieId)

    

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>
            {result
            .find((value) => {value.properties.title == movieId})}
            </h2>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default MovieDetail;
```

UPDATE
This is a link to the whole code in [codesand](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-glade-nslf4?file=/src/App.js) with updated App.js

Answer (score 1):

From your code I'm assuming you're using `React Router v6` in your project. Try the below code:

```
import './App.css';    
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";    
import Home from './components/Home';
import MovieDetail from './components/MovieDetail'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
      <Navbar />
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path=':movieId' element={<MovieDetail />} />
      </Routes>  
    </BrowserRouter>  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Checkout [React Router's Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks Sanket for your help. But, it did not work. Yes, I am using react-router-dom V6.2.1. I just updated the post, I upload the whole code in sandbox. There is a link to it at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios Okay. I'll take look into that and update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using index.js as a wrapper for app.js `<BrowserRouter /> or <Router />` in your case is not used in app.js it's used in index.js otherwise it will not work

**index.js should look like this : -**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return <h1>Hello React Router</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**For example just Let's say you are having *"/movies"* route and you want when ever your app *(route = "/")* starts / loads up to be redirected to "/movies"  **
then wrap the routing logic with `*<Switch />*` ,make use of *Redirect* property of router dom to redirect from "/" to "/movies" and use *component* instead of *element* to render the corresponding component plus dont wrap with *`<Routes> </Routes>`* every time you are doing the route as we used it in index.js

**then app.js will be : -**

```
import './App.css';    
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";    
import Home from './components/Home';
import MovieDetail from './components/MovieDetail'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
      <>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/movies' component={<Home />} />   
            <Route exact path to='movies/:movieId' component={<MovieDetail />} 

    // to redirect from "/" to "/movies"
          <Redirect from="/" to="/students"></Redirect>
```

);
    }

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for your help. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I just upload the code in sandbox. There is a link a in the bottom of the post to it.

Comment: I did make it work using element instead of component. But, I had to comment the line where is the route to movieId.

Comment: iam glad you found the solution , have a good time

Comment: Hi Ahmed. Thanks for your help. I am using some tips from your answer. However, I am still having issues with the dynamic routing. There is a link to codesand on the post if you could have a look.

Comment: i can't open the sandbox link please check

Comment: It works fine for me. This is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-glade-nslf4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Idk , its just showing me black screeen